# syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: c, linux, unix, ubuntu-14.04

Tish is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("77777");

    return 0;
}

yaki@ubuntu:~/Desktop/yakima$ gcc yakima.c -o yakima.o 
yaki@ubuntu:~/Desktop/yakima$ ./yakima.c
```

This is the error:

> ```
> ./yakima.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
> ./yakima.c: line 3: `int main()'
> ```

What can you do with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to execute source file.

After you create object file you have to link object file(s) to binary like

```
gcc -c yakima.c -o yakima.o 
gcc yakima.o -o yakima
```

and execute binary

```
./yakima
```